# How can i generate every 3 days of the month?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, date, datejs

Can someone help me in date.js or javascript, I want to generate every 3 days of the month but the weekends is not included. from there, I want to pass the generated dates in my view in form of list groups. Here are my codes so far. Thank you.

**JS:**

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {

    
    var firstDay = Date.parse("t + 1d");
    var secondDay = Date.parse("t + 2d");
    var thirdDay = Date.parse("t + 3d");

    console.log(firstDay);
    console.log(secondDay);
    console.log(thirdDay);
});
```

**In my view:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h4><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <b>PICK DATE</b></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                   <b><h5><div class="card-header" id="decors_month"></div></h5></b>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal mt-3">
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success text-wrap text-center">01-March-2022 <br> <small> <b>Tuesday</b> </small></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success text-wrap text-center">02-March-2022 <br> <small> <b>Tuesday</b> </small></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success text-wrap text-center">03-March-2022 <br> <small> <b>Tuesday</b> </small></li>
                        <ul class="float-end"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success "><i class="fa fa-hand-o-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>   Pick</button></ul>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                <h4><i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <b>MODULE DATES</b></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I am using Laravel 6. Thank you.

Comment: What does *"every 3 days of the month"* mean? Can you give a few concrete examples of input/output?

Comment: Do you mean the first 3 days of the month or a random 3 days in the month or the last 3 days of the month?

Comment: Every 3 days of the month sir.